# How can Accurev GUI functionality be extended?

Tags: accurev

Is there any way additional commands can be integrated into the GUI as a menu option?

Long story short - we are using a code review tool that does not play nice with the depot natively, so diffs have to be submitted manually. *In a perfect world* we'd have another option in the contextual menu - e.g. when right-clicking on some of the pending files we'd be able to "start a review" similar to how we are able to do "diff against backed"

Again, the code review tool we're using is basically a glorified web-based diff comparison tool with minimal integration, so I'm quite happy to just have an atomic changelist submitted to it.

Current approach that we're working on is chainging the Accurev's custom diff tool path to send the changes to an app that will prompt you to either show diffs locally or start a new code review... needless to say that approach is borderline insane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v.

The AccuRev GUI doesn't have any extensibility in the fashion you described.  You've actually hit upon the "best" workaround that there currently is.

My suggestion: submit an enhancement request to AccuRev.  Specifically, I'd ask for a customizable action menu item.  That way, different customers could utilize it in different ways, depending on their unique needs...

Cheers,
~James

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep an eye out for *better* ways to deal with it but will accept your answer now. I'll see if I could experiment with substituting the popup (show diff/start new review) for a check if, say, `ctrl` key is pressed or something.